# Limit of $x^{1/2} \log x$ as $x$ approaches $0^{-}$.

Tags: calculus, limits

This is how solve it. Is it right? Are there any mistakes here?

$$\lim_{x\to 0^{-}} \sqrt{x}\ln{x}=\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} i\sqrt{x}\bigl((2n+1)πi+\ln{x}\bigr)=\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} -\sqrt{x}(2n+1)π+i\sqrt{x}\ln{x}=\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} -\sqrt{x}(2n+1)π+\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} i\sqrt{x}\ln{x}=0+i\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} \sqrt{x}\ln{x}=0+iL=0$$
Notes: $$L=0$$ is a well-known result and how to solve it is not relevant to this question. $$n\in\Bbb{Z}$$

Answer (score 2):

Well, yes, the result is that the limit is zero.

Another way:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} x^{1/2} \log x = 2\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} x^{1/2} \log x^{1/2} = 2\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} x \log x = 2\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\log x}{\frac{1}{x}} = 2\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\frac{1}{x}}{-\frac{1}{x^2}}=0.$$

Notes:

I.  Used L'Hopitals rule in the last step.

II.  The limits from the left and from the right are the same in this case.

**UPDATE**

I guess your concern is "the limit from the left" ...

Let $x=\epsilon e^{i\pi}$ (same argument if $x=\epsilon e^{i(2n+1)\pi}$)

$$x^{1/2} \log x = \epsilon^{1/2}e^{i\pi/2}(\log \epsilon + i \pi)$$

$$\lim_{x\uparrow 0} x^{1/2} \log x = e^{i\pi/2} \lim_{\epsilon\downarrow 0} \epsilon^{1/2} \log \epsilon  -e^{i\pi/2}\lim_{\epsilon \downarrow 0}\epsilon^{1/2}=0-0=0$$